# How to reference values when iterating an object with #each built-in Handlebars helper?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I try to generate a table out of a JSON response

I know how to access the key **but i do not find a way to get the value**.

```
{{#each this}}
  {{@key}}
{{/each}}
```

Each key will be a row and the value will represent the content of the row (like in the below image)

The response is below :

this:

```
{  
   "DistributedQueue-0":{  
      "MessagesCurrentCount":"0",
      "MessagesPendingCount":"0",
      "MessagesReceivedCount":"0",
      "MessagesHighCount":"0",
      "ConsumersCurrentCount":"0",
      "ConsumersHighCount":"0",
      "ConsumersTotalCount":"0"
   },
   "PatientNotificationQueue":{  
      "MessagesCurrentCount":"0",
      "MessagesPendingCount":"0",
      "MessagesReceivedCount":"0",
      "MessagesHighCount":"0",
      "ConsumersCurrentCount":"0",
      "ConsumersHighCount":"0",
      "ConsumersTotalCount":"0"
   },
   "Topic-0":{  
      "MessagesCurrentCount":"0",
      "MessagesPendingCount":"0",
      "MessagesReceivedCount":"0",
      "MessagesHighCount":"0",
      "ConsumersCurrentCount":"0",
      "ConsumersHighCount":"0",
      "ConsumersTotalCount":"0"
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your html expression code here how your iterating it. Also how are you passing this data to UI?

Comment: for now <script id="dashboard-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
      {{@key}}: ???? (don't know how to get the value)
    {{/each}}
</script>

Comment: `{{#each this}} {{@key}} = {{this}} {{/each}}` - the `{{this}}` inside `each` block should be the value in current iteration.

Comment: and the values inside {{this}} like MessagesCurrentCount ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the element in each iteration is available as `{{this}}` inside a block like `{{#each}}`. So

```
{{#each this}} 
 {{@key}} = {{this}} 
{{/each}}
```

In your case it would render something like

```
KeyName: [object Object]
```

since `{{this}}` now refers to the value, which is an object itself. You know how to iterate over an object using `{{#each}}` - you have just done that. Now you just need to use a nested `{{#each}}` loop! :)

```
{{#each this}}
  {{@key}}: 
    {{#each this}}
      {{@key}}: {{this}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f5feae43/2/